# Numlock & Capslock lights wrong after Lubuntu wake-up

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, suspend, numlock

If I suspend my Lubuntu with either or both the numlock and capslock lights on then later wake it I find both lights off on my keyboard (Micro$oft 600).
Both numlock and capslock remain in the same state as they were before the suspend, it's just the lights that are wrong. If either numlock or capslock key is pressed then both lights correct themselves.
I do not believe this is an issue with the keyboard as it works correctly in XP; only in Lubuntu is there this problem.
Does anyone have ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Two years later, just filled a bug... https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxfind/+bug/1790298